# Creating a ContentView with multiple IView as BindableProperty in MAUI and NET8

Tags: c#, maui, .net-8.0

My goal is to create a *flipcard* to reuse on different pages or projects in `MAUI` application and in particular with `NET8`. The idea is simple. There are a bunch of cards created from a list.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="LanguageInUse.Components.CardStack.FlipCard">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Border StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 10" StrokeThickness="4" Stroke="CadetBlue">
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Header" />
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Body" />
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Footer" />
        </Border>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

I like to have 3 parts of the `ContentView`: the *Header* and the *Footer* that don't change and the *Body*. So, when I pass the *Header* or the *Footer*, the component can add the content immediately.

```
public partial class FlipCard : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty HeaderProperty = 
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Header), typeof(IView), 
            typeof(FlipCard), propertyChanged: OnHeaderPropertyChanged);

    public IView Header
    {
        get => (IView)GetValue(HeaderProperty);
        set => SetValue(HeaderProperty, value);
    }

    static void OnHeaderPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, 
        object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var flipcard = (FlipCard)bindable;
        if (newValue is View view)
            flipcard.HeaderContent.Content = view;
    }
}
```

With the *Body* I like to do something different. I want to have a `BindableProperty` for the *Front* and the *Back*. At the first time, I want to show in the *Body* the *Front*. If the user taps on it, I want to show the *Back*.

I saw this [post](https://vladislavantonyuk.github.io/articles/Creating-a-card-stack-layout-using-.NET-MAUI/) and it is roughly what I like to do but it is using a component to generate the `BindableProperty` and if I try to change the `Content` at run-time, I get an error all the time.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your description, one might start with a grid with a header row, and a footer row, and then a middle row where the `IView` images do their flip. One approach that has worked for me is to implement a "one-hot" by placing another grid in that middle row, and setting a tap gesture to advance a `OneHotVisible` enumeration. In this sample, I'm just using `Front` and `Back` but you can have any number of values.

[image: front and back alternate]

The IView objects, like front and back, are just piled on top of each other in that middle Grid, but only one is ever visible because changes of the `OneHotVisible` property are translated using `IValueConverter` to tell each view whether to show itself or not.

---

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:front_and_back"
             x:Class="front_and_back.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:OneHotToVisibilityConverterFront x:Key="FrontConverter" />
            <local:OneHotToVisibilityConverterBack x:Key="BackConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <Grid
        x:Name="TableLayoutPanel"
        Padding="30,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label 
            Grid.Row="0"
            Text="Header"
            FontSize="32"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <Grid   
            Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TappedCommand}" />
            </Grid.GestureRecognizers>            
            <ContentView
                IsVisible="{Binding OneHotVisible, Converter={StaticResource FrontConverter}}">
                <Label
                    Text="Front!"
                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                    BackgroundColor="LightBlue"
                    FontSize="32"
                    HorizontalOptions="Fill" />  
            </ContentView>
            <ContentView  
                IsVisible="{Binding OneHotVisible, Converter={StaticResource BackConverter}}">
                <Label
                    Text="Back!"
                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                    BackgroundColor="LightGreen"
                    FontSize="32"
                    HorizontalOptions="Fill" />
            </ContentView>
        </Grid>
        <Label 
            Grid.Row="2"
            Text="Footer"
            FontSize="32"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

**Main Page**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        BindingContext = new MainPageBinding();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

---

**Main View Model**

```
public enum OneHotVisible
{
    Front,
    Back,
}
class MainPageBinding : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainPageBinding()
    {
        TappedCommand = new Command(OnTapped);
    }
    public OneHotVisible OneHotVisible
    {
        get => _oneHotVisible;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_oneHotVisible, value))
            {
                _oneHotVisible = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    OneHotVisible _oneHotVisible = 0;
    public ICommand TappedCommand { get; private set; }
    private void OnTapped(object o)
    {
        OneHotVisible = (OneHotVisible)((((int)OneHotVisible) + 1) % 2);
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string caller = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
    }
}
```

---

**IValueConverters**

```
public class OneHotToVisibilityConverterFront : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) =>
        (value is OneHotVisible oneHotVisible && oneHotVisible == OneHotVisible.Front);
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public class OneHotToVisibilityConverterBack : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) =>
        (value is OneHotVisible oneHotVisible && oneHotVisible == OneHotVisible.Back);
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

I hope this might offer a starting point to experiment with.

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/front-and-back.git) this sample.

Comment: I'm looking at it right now. Thank you so much